# HTML5 Canvas onmousedown Event in Android 4.0 ICS odd behaviour

Tags: android, html, html5-canvas, onmousedown

I've got a basic HTML drawing application using the jQuery lib [Sketch.js](http://intridea.github.com/sketch.js/) (which uses < canvas>, works perfectly fine on IE, Opera, Chrome, Firefox on all desktop browsers. Works fine on Opera Mobile, Chrome Mobile, Firefox Mobile, Dolphin HD, Android stock browser 2.2.4.

*But when i test it on Android 4.0 stock browser, on either a tablet or a phone, when i press on the < canvas> element, the box gets highlighted in blue and the touch event starts in the center, regardless of where the finger actually is, and THEN it goes back and tracks the finger like normal. Obviously every time the element gets touched, an unneeded line gets drawn when on that particular browser.*

For testing I tried disabling sketch.js and just made a generic onmousedown event with an alert. When this happens the whole canvas gets highlighted in blue once more, and I imagine the same behavior occurs. When I go to [Sketch.js](http://intridea.github.com/sketch.js/) website, the exact same behavior happens....

**Is there any known work around for this behavior?** Or is there an alternative to [Sketch.js](http://intridea.github.com/sketch.js/) which doesn't exhibit this behavior? (I imagine all < canvas> elements with onmousedown events are exactly the same though)

For completeness this is the HTML+JS:

```
<canvas  style="border:1pt solid black;margin:auto;cursor:crosshair;clear:both;"  width="450px" height="200px" id="colors_sketch" ></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function() {
        $('#colors_sketch').sketch();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I sort of found a solution, I used a different lib to perform the same functionality: http://www.unbolt.net/jSignature/ this didn't have the issue, saddly i couldn't resolve the above issue exactly.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason, the browser messed with mouse events even in touch screens.

To solve this, just set the mousedown, mouseup, mousemove events to undefined in your ontouchstart event.